# tsql month problem

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like:

```
id   month   cost
------------------
1    Jan      200
1    Mar      204
1    May      200
1    Dec      201
```

I need an output like( order by month including the other months of a year-displaying all 12 months):

```
to   month   cost
------------------
1    Jan      200
NULL Feb      NULL
1    Mar      204
....
....
....
1    Dec      201
```

any idea or solution how to do this in TSQL?

Thanks!

edit:: month is extracted from a datetime value.
in real world i'll have to show previous 12 months from last month in a DESC order! any suggestion for that?

Comment: Does your data really contain only month in CHAR(3) form or is it a date? Otherwise, how do you identify Oct last year, or are there only 12 records that roll around?

Comment: Can you change that table schema? Seems it would be more convenient in the long term (manages years as well) to just use a DATETIME column, which you can easily sort by and from which you can easily get the 'Jan'-type representation. By using MONTH(dateTimeCol) you would get the month number

Comment: Here is the SQL to get the abbreviated month name from a DATETIME column: `CONVERT(nchar(3), dateTimeCol, 100)`. Usually, if you want to store the month in a database, you would set day, seconds, and so forth of it to zero.

Comment: @skarmats - i've already mentioned that i got from datetime!! DATEPART(month, somedate) as 'Month'

Comment: ok. so just to understand this - the base table does not contain every month so you need to fill in the months, that are not in the base table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?
The result contains month and year, but you can strip it as you want.

```
;with months
as
(
select dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)) as m
union all
select dateadd(month, -1, m)
from months
where   m > dateadd(month, -12, getdate())
)

-- Testdata
,yourTable(id,somedate,cost)
as
(
    select 1, '2011-01-03', 200
    union all
    select 1, '2011-03-06', 204
    union all
    select 1, '2010-05-09', 200
    union all
    select 1, '2010-05-19', 201
    union all
    select 1, '2010-12-02', 201
)
-- end testdata

select  yt.id
        ,datename(month,coalesce(yt.somedate, m.m)) as [month]
        ,datename(year,coalesce(yt.somedate, m.m)) as [year]
        --,yt.cost
        ,sum(yt.cost) as cost
from    months m
left join yourTable yt
    on  datepart(year, yt.someDate) = DATEPART(year, m.m)
    and datepart(month, yt.someDate) = DATEPART(month, m.m)
group by
    yt.id
    ,datename(month,coalesce(yt.somedate, m.m))
    ,datename(year,coalesce(yt.somedate, m.m))
    ,m.m
order by m.m desc
```

Edit: Altered solution to support sum.
Remove the `group by`-section and alter the comment of cost, to get the old solution.

Comment: Thanks @Johan. It is very impressive. but i cant group the rows to get sum of the cost if i have 2 rows for one months. do you know why?

Comment: @Iternity - I have no probelm doing that. But I am not sure how you want the result to be. I altered the solution as I think you wanted it.

Answer (score 5):

Try building a reference table of months, and `JOIN`ing on it. It's the quickest way to do this with months in varchar datatype.

```
declare @foo table (id int, [mon] varchar(100), cost int)    
declare @mon table (mon varchar(100), orderWeight int)

INSERT INTO @mon (mon, orderWeight)
   VALUES ('Jan',1), ('Feb',2),('Mar',3),('Apr',4),('May',5),('Jun',6),('Jul',7),
          ('Aug',8),('Sep',9),('Oct',10),('Nov',11),('Dec',12)

INSERT INTO @foo(id, [mon], cost)
VALUES ( 1    ,'Jan' ,     200),
( 1    ,'Mar',      204),
( 1    ,'May' ,    200),
( 1    ,'Dec'  ,    201)

select f.id,
       m.[mon] , 
       f.cost
from @mon as m 
left join @foo as f on m.mon = f.mon
order by m.orderWeight
```

Results:

[image]

Your ordering will now be guaranteed with the `order by orderWeight`.

Comment: Ha!...you just beat me to the punch :)

Comment: Beat me too while I was testing my syntax - @p. campbell is quick on the draw.

Comment: thanks @p.campbell! very straight forward solution. but still I'm not sure if creating a reference table for moth would solve my problem because in real world i'll have to show previous 12 months from last month in a DESC order! any suggestion for that?

Comment: @Iternity: right... you'd have to then include the Year in your base table, then `order by MyYear, orderWeight`

Comment: @p.campbell i'm afraid i can not change the base table..:(

Comment: @p.campbell: According to the edit on the OP, he is getting the Month from a DATETIME column in the base table

Comment: @skarmats: right... I'd answered according to v1 of the question. Keeping up with changing requirements on questions is *fun*. It was **presented** as a character value, so that's what I wrote my answer to. It's unfortunate, as the real answer will have THAT as part of the solution. If it'd been presented as close to reality, I'd probably have had a better answer than above. As it stands, my answer is skewed for the question as it was written.

Answer (score 2):

Sample table

```
create table mytable(id int, dt datetime, cost money)
insert mytable values
(1,GETDATE()-10,200),
(1,GETDATE()-40,204),
(1,GETDATE()-100,200),
(1,GETDATE()-200,201);
```

The query, using SQL Server 2008 specific syntax, and sorted properly

```
select
    t.id [to],
    CONVERT(char(3),dateadd(month,-M.N,L.PVT),7) [Month],
    sum(t.cost) totalCost
from (select PVT=dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-1,0)) L
cross join (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) M(N)
left join mytable t
    on t.dt >= dateadd(month,-M.N,L.PVT)
   and t.dt <  dateadd(month,-M.N+1,L.PVT)
group by t.id, right(CONVERT(char(9),dt,6),6), M.N, L.PVT
order by M.N
```

What it does:

1. `right(CONVERT(char(9),dt,6),6)` converts a date into the format 'DD MMM YY', we only need the `MMM YY` part
2. In the SELECT, we further extract only the 3-char month from it, using LEFT( , 3)
3. The subquery L has a single record and column, PVT, which is the first date of the last month
4. The number series 0-11 is used to create the month values for the last 12 months, using the formula `dateadd(month,-M.N,L.PVT)`
5. The range `t.dt >= .. and t.dt < ..` finds data for a single month

Comment: any suggestion to the change @Richard?